# Programmatically add tabs to tab host

Tags: android, xml, tabs, addition

I would like to know the easiest way to programmatically add tabs to a tab host (e.g. by pressing a button). In other words without hard coding its structure in the XML file.

Comment: [Adding tabs dynamically](http://www.androidguys.com/2008/08/12/adding-tabs-dynamically/)

Answer (score 2):

One way to programmatically create a tab and populate it with content is to:

1. Define a separate layout file
2. Define a *Tab Content Factory class* that inflates the layout and returns the resulting view after taking care of evantual customizations
3. Use the Factory class as an argument to the `TabSpec.setContent` method

### Example

**Seperate Layout.axml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px">
    <TextView
        android:text="Kablam"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/kablamTextView" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**TabContent Factory class** (defined as a inner class in an `Activity` => `this` is the activity instance)

```
private class MyTabContentFactory implements TabContentFactory {
   public View CreateTabContent(string tag) {

      View view = this.getLayoutInflater()
             .inflate(R.layout.Layout, (ViewGroup)this.FindViewById(R.id.tabHost1), false);

      ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.kablamTextView))
         .setText("Some sentence which can be generated dynamically");
      return view;
    }
}
```

And finally to build on [Hemendra Sharma](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1673002/hemendra-sharma)'s answer, **using the tab factory to define the content**

```
TabHost tabHost = (TabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
tabHost.setup();

TabSpec tab1 = tabHost.newTabSpec("Tab_Name");
tab1.setIndicator("Tab 1");

tab1.setContent(new MyTabContentFactory());

tabHost.addTab(tab1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple way to programmatically add tabs on TabHost.

```
TabHost tabHost = (TabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
tabHost.setup();

TabSpec tab1 = tabHost.newTabSpec("Tab_Name");
View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.tab_indicator,
        myLayout, false);
tab1.setIndicator(view);
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyActivity.class);
tab1.setContent(i);

tabHost.addTab(tab1);
```

Good Luck. :)

Comment: So first of all thank you very very much for your kind help. The problem is that I'm a total newbie trying to do things difficult for me. So the question is: with the line   View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.tab_indicator,myLayout, false); how can I set mylayout and tab_indicator? It's dinamic so I can't store it in activity_main.xml can I?

Comment: Create a new XML layout file for your indicator. It won't be inside activity_main.xml .

Comment: Thank you again @Hemendra. So I created the tab_layout.xml in the layout dir. This layout has the line android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01". My last problem is: in the line View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.tab_indicator,
        myLayout, false); what is the myLayout var set to? thanx again and sorry for my clumsiness...

Answer (score 0):

On Button click event, try this

```
myTabHost =(TabHost) findViewById(R.id.tabhostId);
mytabhost.setup();
TabSpec spec = mytabhost.newTabSpec("tab_creation");
 spec.setIndicator("TAB_NAME",getResources().getDrawable(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_add));// text and image of tab
spec.setContent(R.id.layout_of_tab); // layout of tab
mytabhost.addTab(spec);
```